# How to Convert String to Variable Name in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

hope you are all doing great.
I want to know is there any way we can convert string to a variable name? I want to convert `"minXLabel"` to `minXLabel` and use it inside `span` tags like this `<span>{{minXLabel}</span>`
I have

```js
        <div class="placeholder-value">
         <span>{{  inputsArray[index].firstOption || placeholder[index].first}} - </span> 
         <span>{{  inputsArray[index].secondOption || placeholder[index].second}}</span> 
       </div>
```

and the input array is

```js
 inputsArray : [
        { 'firstOption': "minXLabel", 'secondOption': "maxXLabel" },
        { 'firstOption': "minXLabel", 'secondOption': "minYLabel" },
        { 'firstOption': "maxYLabel", 'secondOption': "maxXLabel" },
        { 'firstOption': "maxYLabel", 'secondOption': "minYLabel" }
      ],
```

I can do that manually with `<span>{{  minXLabel || placeholder[index].first}} - </span>` but because I want to output in a loop with different keys I need to convert that string into a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform a string to variable using eval function, something like this

```
 const inputsArray = [
    { 'firstOption': "minXLabel", 'secondOption': "maxXLabel" },
    { 'firstOption': "minXLabel", 'secondOption': "minYLabel" },
    { 'firstOption': "maxYLabel", 'secondOption': "maxXLabel" },
    { 'firstOption': "maxYLabel", 'secondOption': "minYLabel" }
  ]

  const iterator = inputsArray.values()

  for (let item of iterator) {
    const variableName = eval(item.firstOption);
    console.log(variableName)
  }
```

However, these variables will not be declared, you can assign value if you want for example `inputsArray[index].firstOption || placeholder[index].first` and then use the variable.

However, looks a little redundant that you try to assign a value that you already have to a new variable. For me, your first approach is correct just loop over your array and render the info there

```
<div v-for="item in placeholder">
  <div v-for="input in inputsArray" class="placeholder-value">
     <span>{{  input.firstOption || item.first}} - </span> 
     <span>{{  input.secondOption || item.second}}</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: eval() is not available inside {{  }}

Comment: You are using Vue, you can create a function to use JS code, assign the variable(s) there and just render in a loop the variable in your HTML, is not a good practice to have all the logic inside of your {{}}

Comment: Before asking question I have tried to store all the values in a data(){} function but the values I want to display here are preview of another component. This means if I change those inputs these values should change immediately which doesn't happen in data(){} case.